# Creating Clustered Column Chart in Excel by using Python and openpyxl library

Tags: python, excel

In Excel I have this table that summarize some rainfalls per year:
[image]

I'm trying to generate a Clustered Column Chart like in the below image (the graph was created by hand but I want to be automatically generated by the script):
[image]

With the following script I'm getting this table:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference
import string

excel_file = pd.read_excel('Date_meteo.xlsx')
excel_file[['Tip_precipitatie', 'Ani', 'Precipitatii']]

report_table = excel_file.pivot_table(index='Tip_precipitatie',
                                      columns='Ani',
                                      values='Precipitatii',
                                      aggfunc='sum').round(0)


report_table.to_excel('Raport_meteo.xlsx',
                      sheet_name='Raport',
                      startrow=4)


wb = load_workbook('Raport_meteo.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Raport']

min_column = wb.active.min_column
max_column = wb.active.max_column
min_row = wb.active.min_row
max_row = wb.active.max_row

wb = load_workbook('Raport_meteo.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Raport']

barchart = BarChart()

data = Reference(sheet,
                 min_col=min_column+1,
                 max_col=max_column,
                 min_row=min_row,
                 max_row=max_row) 
categories = Reference(sheet,
                       min_col=min_column,
                       max_col=min_column,
                       min_row=min_row+1,
                       max_row=max_row) 

barchart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
barchart.set_categories(categories)

sheet.add_chart(barchart, "B12")
barchart.title = 'Tip precipitatii anuale'
barchart.style = 5 

wb.save('Raport_meteo.xlsx')

sheet['B7'] = '=SUM(B5:B6)'
sheet['B7'].style = 'Total'

import string
alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
excel_alphabet = alphabet[0:max_column] 
print(excel_alphabet)

wb = load_workbook('Raport_meteo.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Raport']

for i in excel_alphabet:
    if i!='A':
        sheet[f'{i}{max_row+1}'] = f'=SUM({i}{min_row+1}:{i}{max_row})'
        sheet[f'{i}{max_row+1}'].style = 'Total'

sheet[f'{excel_alphabet[0]}{max_row+1}'] = 'Total'
wb.save('Raport_meteo.xlsx')

wb = load_workbook('Raport_meteo.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Raport']
sheet['A1'] = 'Tip precipitatii anuale'
sheet['A2'] = 'Perioada de referinta: 2010-2023'
sheet['A1'].font = Font('Arial', bold=True, size=20)
sheet['A2'].font = Font('Arial', bold=True, size=10)
wb.save('Raport_meteo.xlsx')
```

I'm looking for a solution to get the chart as in the example